# Java 8: Reverse an int array in one line (using Streams API)

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, reverse

I'm trying to solve a [challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/one-semicolon-array-reversal/train/java) which requires you to reverse an `int` array in Java. The catch is that you only get one `;`, so I'm assuming you need to use Streams API to do this.

I tried the conventional way, it reverses the array properly, but fails the one semicolon test -

```
  public static int[] reverse(int[] a) {
    List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.reverse(numbers);
    return numbers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
  }
```

Next, I tried using [Collections.reversedOrder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) -

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).boxed()
     .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
     .mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
  }
```

However, since `Collections.reversedOrder()` impopses the **reverse** of the **natural ordering** of the elements in the collection, if the array consists of numbers 1 through 5, no matter what the order of elements in the array are, it will always return `{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`.

There is a [Comparator.reversed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) method, but it needs to be called on an existing Comparator. I'm not sure how to do that, or if that would even work.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hint: `IntStream.iterate` to create a reverse sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by inverting an index stream:

```
return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
        .map(i -> a[a.length - 1 - i])
        .toArray();
```

Comment: The same as the solution in the duplicate. (not downvoting, just commenting)

Comment: I want `Reverse()` method from LINQ.